# Logback 1.1.11 totalSizeCap not working

Tags: logback

I have the following logback.xml configuration for my spring application. I'm using a SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy, and I pretend to orginize the logs on a montlhy basis (that's the `%d{yyyy-MM, aux}` part.

For debuggin purposes, currently I'm generating a lot of logs, but the totalSizeCap doesn't seem to work. I have a folder for January that is almost 8GB.

¿Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I saw this post [Logback: SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy not honoring totalSizeCap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014221/logback-sizeandtimebasedrollingpolicy-not-honoring-totalsizecap) , but it says it is a bug of logback 1.1.7 and I'm using logback 1.1.11.

```
<property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}"/>

<appender name="RollingFile-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/rollingfile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/rollingfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>50</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5level %r --- %yellow([%.40thread]) %.40logger{10}: %msg%n%throwable</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a bug for `totalSizeCap` ~2GB for logback versions < 1.2.0. Check [LOGBACK-1231](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1231) for more details

Comment: Great! This seems promising. I will check if it works and then accept your answer